# Updating data from onstate() in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I just got started with Svelte/Sapper and there's this silly thing I'm not getting. Maybe it's because I'm used to Vue and I'm not understanding Svelte's paradigm.

I'm basically making a slider or carousel. For that I need to know what is the current section to be shown (which will help determine the entry animation) and keep on record the previous section (just for as long as it needs to transition out).

I'm guessing I can have a

```
<button on:click="set({ section: 'products'})">Go to Products</button>
```

to switch sections, and this works fine. But then I want to have a detection in onstate() so that when the section is changed, the prop prevSection gets updated as well.

Here's the (relevant) code I have so far :

```
<h1>Current section : {section}</h1>
<button on:click="set({ section: 'products'})">Go to Products</button>
<button on:click="set({ section: 'hr'})">Go to HR</button>
<button on:click="set({ section: 'verticals'})">Go to Verticals</button>
<div id="container">
    <Slideshow bind:section></Slideshow>
    <Slideshow bind:prevSection></Slideshow>
</div>

<style>/* Not important */</style>

<script>
    export default {
        onstate({ changed, current, previous }) {
            if (changed.section && previous) {
                this.set({prevSection: previous.section});
            }
        },

        oncreate() {},
        onupdate() {},
        ondestroy() {},

        components: {
            Slideshow: '../components/Slideshow.html'
        },

        data() {
            return {
                section : 'products',
                prevSection : ''
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'd like to have an initial state where section=products and prevSection is empty, and then every time I click a button, prevSection  takes the values of section, and then section updates to the new value dictated by the button.

Thanks so much for your help !

Comment: Off-topic but if you're just getting started with svelte, be sure to check v3, it is a huge improve over v2. [Portal](https://v3.svelte.technology)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the problem wasn't with the code itself, it's that the

```
<Slideshow bind:prevSection></Slideshow>
```

is obviously receiving the **prevSection** prop, but I was trying to console.log() the **section** attribute. So the code was kinda working, I was just checking the wrong prop.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to answer or even just look at it !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I was able to get the section and prevSection variables to update correctly in your example by moving the logic from onstate to onupdate